# Unable to load chan_mobile asterisk

Tags: bluetooth, asterisk

I have been trying to connect my Asterisk 1.8 to a bluetooth via chan_mobile.so for half a day now. Just failed like crazy.

I read some posts where they recommended

```
cd addons
./configure 
make menuselect
```

This failed since ./configure does not exist in addos folder any more for 1.8 (it used to be there in 1.4 and 1.6)

I then read a few more posts and they recommended

```
./configure --with-bluetooth
```

This too failed,

```
configure: ***
configure: *** The BLUETOOTH installation appears to be missing or broken.
configure: *** Either correct the installation, or run configure
configure: *** including --without-bluetooth.
```

But thats the point right, with-bluetooth, da!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read a bit more and found the right answer to it all, I was missing the `libbluetooth-dev`. So all I had to do was to `sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev` and the ./configure --with-bluetooth worked.

After you get `.configure` working, you need to run a `make`, `make install` and `make menuselect`. On running `menuselect`, hit AddOns and enable `[ ]` on chan_mobile with a `[*]`, hit `Esc` and `S` for save.

Also check `/etc/asterisk/modules` for

> > load => chan_mobile.so

To test

> > asterisk -vc | grep mobile

With so less support for quick answers on **asterisk getting started**, I thought it would be best to share a Q and A on SO.

Comment: Thank you for proivding this answer, it saved me having to look for which BT modules asterisk required.